# Geometry Question on Area Lemma

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In ∆ABC, AB = AC = 115, AD = 38, and CF = 77 where D lies on AB and F lies on AC produced. DF intersects BC at E. Compute
$$ {[CEF]\over [DBE]} $$

This question is from Pathfinder For Olympiad Mathematics.

I tried solving this question by Base Division Theorem: by finding ratio between DE and FE, but got stuck in the beginning.
I then thought of Menelaus, but I am confused in which triangle I should apply, and which line to take a s Menelaus Line.
Here's what I did:

- Menelaus, $\frac{CE}{CB} \cdot \frac{AB}{AD} \cdot \frac{DF}{FE}=1$, so $\frac{CE}{CB} \cdot \frac{DF}{FE}=\frac{38}{115}$. Let $\frac{CE}{CB}=\frac{2}{5}, \frac{DF}{FE}=\frac{19}{23}$. From the sine area formula the ratio of the areas is just $\frac{CE \cdot EF}{EB \cdot ED}$. We have $\frac{CE}{EB}=\frac{2}{7}$ and $\frac{EF}{ED}=\frac{23}{42}$, so multiplying gives $\boxed{\frac{23}{147}}$. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The two triangles have the same altitude (on base $BEC$), hence the ratio of the areas is the same as $CE/BE$.

Comment: "Did I make a mistake somewhere?" How do you know that ${CE\over CB}={2/5}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Menelaus
$$\frac{FC}{FA}\times \frac{AD}{DB}\times \frac{BE}{EC}=1$$

$$\frac{77}{192}\times \frac{38}{77}\times \frac{BE}{EC}=1$$

$$\frac{BE}{EC}=\frac {96}{19}$$

Since $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles with $AB=AC$ and $BD=CF$

$$ {[CEF]\over [DBE]}=\frac{EC}{BE}=\frac {19}{96}$$

[image]

Draw $DH$ and $FG$ perpendicular to $BC$

Since $\triangle DBH \cong \triangle FCG$, $DH=FG$

Comment: Would you please explain the last step? I didn't get it.

Comment: We have that $\frac{[DBE]}{[CEF]}=\frac{BD\cdot BE\sin \angle ABC}{CF\cdot CE\sin\angle ECF}=\frac{BE\cdot 77}{CE\cdot 77}=\frac{BE}{EC}$.

Comment: As I wrote above in a comment, triangles $CEF$ and $DBE$ have the same altitude on base $BEC$, hence the ratio of their areas is the same as $/$.